# Can you have multiple e-mail configurations for Carthrob?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm running EE 2.5.2 and Cartthrob 2.0506 and need to setup an additional customer e-mail for just a few of our products. To make a long story short we have two different groups of products and the majority are in the first group and once a product is purchased the admin e-mail is sent to me and also to the vendor that fulfills these orders then the vendor actually sends an invoice to the customer. Initially the customer e-mail sent just informs them that the order was received and to expect an invoice from the vendor soon, that all works great. However the secondary group of products does not need to e-mail this vendor but rather just e-mail the invoice directly to the customer. Is there anyway to get Cartthrob setup with a product based condition for the e-mails sent? Maybe a multiple stores setting or something that would give me a fresh set of options under the e-mail button on the settings page. Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this sort of thing via Postmaster and Stash.  I have found trying to do any complex stuff in CT direct emails is very hard/impossible

Have a look at:
[How is a postmaster Cart Throb on authorize hook mail formed?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/23945/how-is-a-postmaster-cart-throb-on-authorize-hook-mail-formed/23995#23995)